# algorithm to replicate data between computers

Tags: algorithm, replication

Suppose I have n computers. Each of them has a set of integers. Each computer will not have the same set.

i.e. computer 1 has {1,2,3,4}, computer 2 has {4, 5,10,20,21}, computer 3 has {-10,3,5} and so on.

I want to replicate this data so that all computers will have all the integers , i.e. all of them will have {-10,1,2,3,4,5,10,20,21}

I want to minimize the number of messages that each computer sends and also minimize the time. (i.e. avoid a serial approach where computer 1 first communicates with everyone and gets the data it is missing, then computer 2 does the same and so on.

What is an efficient way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like BitTorrent ?

Comment: Edited problem spec to make it specific to a set of integers

Comment: Do the machines know how many other systems there are and who they are (i.e. does computer 1 know that only 2 & 3 exist)?  Are you more concerned with minimizing the number of messages?  Or the time?  It is highly unlikely that the algorithm to minimize one will minimize the other.  Do we assume that it takes the same amount of time to send messages between any two computers?

Comment: @Justin: Yes, all computers know about all others. We can also assume that the graph topology or Minimal Spanning tree is also known statically. I am fine with just assuming that each computer takes the same time to communicate with any other computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Minimal approach would be : All computers send info to just one ( master ) computer and get the result

For reliability you could consider at least two computers as master computers

> Assumptions :

1. Total n computers
2. One of the computers is considered as master

> Algorithm :

1. All computers send `input-info` to Master ( total n-1 messages )
2. Master processes the info
3. Master sends the `result-info` to all computers ( total n-1 messages )

> Reliability :

Total failure of the system based on this algorithm can only occur if all the masters failed .

> Efficiency :

```
With 1 master  , total messages : 2 * (n-1)
With 2 masters , total messages : 2 * 2 * (n-1)
With 3 masters , total messages : 3 * 2 * (n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the computers are on the same network, you could use UDP sockets with SO_BROADCAST option.

This way when one computer does a message 'send', all the other computers would 'recv' the message and update as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it in 2*n - 2 moves. Model the machines as nodes in a linked-list and numbered from 1..n.

1. Let node 1 send all of its data in one message to node 2.
2. Node 2 remembers the message node 1 sent, performs a union of its content with node 1's content and sends the unified message to Node 3. Then Node 2 waits for a response from Node 3.
3. Node 3 does the same as above and so on until we get to node 'n'. Node 'n' now has the complete set.
4. Node 'n' already knows what message node 'n - 1' sent it, so it sends the diff back to node 'n - 1'
5. Node 'n - 1' performs the union as above. Since it has remembered the message of node 'n - 2' (in step 2 above), it can send the diff back to node 'n - 3'

and so on.

I think it is not complex to show that the above leads to 2 * (n - 1) messages being sent in the network.

I think it can be proven that 2n - 2 is necessary by considering each node to have a unique element. It should be a short exercise in mathematical induction to prove that 2n - 2 is necessary..

Comment: Yes, this would work. I think I can speed it up further by having both ends of the linked list start the process simultaneosly so that the middle computer is the one that is the first to gather the whole set and then it starts the process again to its left and right.

Comment: Yes it can be parallelized as much as you want

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's already a system that does this, is widely adopted, well documented, widely available and, while it's perhaps not perfect (for assorted definitions of perfect), it's practical.

It's called RSync.

You can start here: http://www.samba.org/~tridge/phd_thesis.pdf